# How to connect js array to highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am new to Java Script and Highcharts have a question that may be basic but have not been able to find a response in the internet. Basically, I want to connect the data generated by a user to a highchart and the question is how that linkage is done

say I have a code that generates some values like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Diameter: <input type="number" id="TreeDiameter" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var Results="";
var TreeDiameter = document.getElementById("TreeDiameter").value;
  for (i = 1; i <=20; i++) {
  r = i  + TreeDiameter;
  Results += r + ",";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = RESULTS;
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
```

I want those value to be plotted in a Highchart like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>

<div id="container" style="width:50%; height:400px;"></div>



<script> 
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'x'
            },
        title: {
        text: 'CO2 stored by your tree'
        },

            xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minRange: 365 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
                text: 'CO2 sequestered (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity    (0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 2
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            threshold: null
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Cummulative CO2 stored',
        pointInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
        data: [RESULTS]
    }]
});
});

</script>



    </body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the "RESULTS" from the first code are plotted in the second?. If possible, I would like to maintain both codes in a single page. Thanks.

Comment: can you do a jsFiddle?

Comment: Of course it is possible and needed since on the other page you did not define RESULTS. you either need them to being parsed to the next site or simply put both codes together. But we will not build you a website with two sample codes. You have to provide your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, you can change the time interval of setTimeout function based on the number of for loops or iteration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Diameter: <input type="number" id="TreeDiameter" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="container" style="width:50%; height:400px;"></div>
</body>

<script>
var Results=[];
function myFunction() {

var TreeDiameter = document.getElementById("TreeDiameter").value;
  for (i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
  var r = i  + TreeDiameter;
  Results[i]=parseInt(r);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Results;


setTimeout(function(){


    var Results1=Results;


 $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'x'
            },
        title: {
        text: 'CO2 stored by your tree'
        },

            xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            minRange: 365 * 24 * 3600000 // fourteen days
        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
                text: 'CO2 sequestered (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity    (0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            },
            marker: {
                radius: 2
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            },
            threshold: null
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Cummulative CO2 stored',
        pointInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600000,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
        data:Results1
    }]
});

}, 1000);

}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sherya, that was a smart solution. originally i thought the solution was to first run one function and then apply the results to the next one. But this works, as well. Thank you very much for your help.